# How to avoid anchors to restart music when using audio tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, audio, anchor, html5-audio

I have create an HTML page, with the  tag (proper for playing HTML5 mp3 audio).

The problem is that I have links with anchors, and Internet Explorer 9 browser is playing back the audio from start: each click on anchors to the same page is restarting the music.

The links are:

```
< a href="#bio" > Biography < /a>

< a href="#contact" > Contact < /a>
...
```

The anchors are:

```
<a name="bio"></a>
...
<a name="contact"></a>
...
```

and the audio tag is

```
<audio id="hello" src="hello.mp3" controls preload="auto" 
autobuffer style="display:none"></audio>
```

How can I avoid the restart of the music when user clicks on links with anchors?

Comment: Your anchors should be `<a id="bio"></a>`, `name` was deprecated in HTML4, let alone HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

@robertc, nice!

Replacing anchors' `name` property with `id` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

To be complete: IE fires the Document.onLoad event when following a link to a name="", whereas they do not if you use an id=""  .  Moz / Safari / Chrome / Opera don't fire it in either case.